# generating redheffer matrix using cuda

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have an assignment that requires me to generate Redheffer matrix on GPU using Cuda.

```
A Redheffer matrix1 is a matrix where each entry a[i][j] is defined by  
a[i][j] =  
1 if j = 1,   
1 if j is divisible by i  
0 otherwise.
```

Here is my code

```
    #define SIZE = 20000
    #define BLOCK_WIDTH 16

   /* Launch the CUDA kernel */
    int numBlocks = ceil(SIZE / BLOCK_WIDTH);
    dim3 dimGrid(BLOCK_WIDTH,BLOCK_WIDTH,1);
    dim3 dimBlock(numBlocks,numBlocks,1);
    redhefferMatrix<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_M, SIZE);
```

I have code to verify if the output is right, it return error message when matrix element value computed is not correct.
When I run my program, I get this error.

```
GPU number 0 is assigned to this job
    Row 0 column 5000 is incorrect. Should be:1 Is actually: 0
```

My logic to compute values is

```
int Row= blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
int Col= blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
.
.
if(i < 20000 && j < 20000)
{   

    {

        if(j == 1 || j % i == 0)
            d_M[i*SIZE+ j] = 1;
        else
            d_M[i*SIZE+ j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Can someone give me an idea where i might be wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided a complete code, it's not possible to determine all the issues that may be present. But you have a misinterpretation of block and grid dimensions (you have them reversed):

```
#define SIZE = 20000
#define BLOCK_WIDTH 16

/* Launch the CUDA kernel */
int numBlocks = ceil(SIZE / BLOCK_WIDTH);
dim3 dimGrid(BLOCK_WIDTH,BLOCK_WIDTH,1);
dim3 dimBlock(numBlocks,numBlocks,1);
redhefferMatrix<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_M, SIZE);
```

The first kernel configuration parameter should be the dimensions of the *grid* in terms of number of blocks (in x and y, in this case).  Your first kernel config parameter is `dimGrid` which you have defined as a `dim3(BLOCK_WIDTH,BLOCK_WIDTH)` quantity, i.e. 16x16 blocks.    That's not what you intended I don't think, but not actually illegal.

Your second kernel configuration parameter should be the dimensions of the *block* in terms of number of threads (in x and y, in this case).  Your second kernel parameter is `dimBlocks`, which you have defined as  a `dim3(20000/16, 20000/16)` quantity, i.e. 1250x1250 threads.  This is illegal, as CUDA threadblocks are limited to a *total* of 1024 threads, i.e. the product of the dimensions cannot exceed 1024.

So your kernel launch is illegal and your kernel is not even running.  If you use [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) and/or run your code with `cuda-memcheck`, you would discover this.

The fix may be fairly simple - reverse your sense of these config parameters:

```
dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_WIDTH,BLOCK_WIDTH,1);
dim3 dimGrid(numBlocks,numBlocks,1);
```

Again, I cannot say this is the only issue, since you have not shown a complete code that I could actually test (which SO [expects](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for questions like this.)

If you make the above change and things are still not working, I would suggest the following:

1. Add the proper cuda error checking and run your code with `cuda-memcheck` as I already suggested.
2. Provide a [complete MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. a complete code that somebody else could copy, paste, and run.  Also provide whatever is the output of the `cuda-memcheck` and error-checking on your system.

You should do the above 2 things *before* you ask for debugging help here on SO.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It helped.